# Functions in bash with special parameters

Tags: bash

in a bash script I am implementing some functions, that take parameters

The problem is when the parameters instaed of being MONDAY is END OF THE WEEK

How can I pass this parameter to the function so the function

```
function week{
TIME=$1
}
```

takes a `$TIME` "**`END OF THE WEEK`**" and not just "**`END`**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
TIME="$*"
```

to get *all* of the parameters strung together, as in:

```
#!/bin/bash
function week {
        TIME="$*"
        echo "${TIME}"
}
week end of the week
```

which produces (all four arguments used):

```
end of the week
```

If you want to preserve white space. you can pass it as a quoted string.

```
#!/bin/bash
function week {
        TIME="$*"
        echo "${TIME}"
}
week "end        of the week"
```

which produces (from a *single* argument):

```
end        of the week
```

Answer (score 2):

Enclose a variable in double quotes to prevent word splitting but interpolate the variable's value. Single quoted strings undergo even less processing.

```
function week {
    TIME="$1"
}

week 'END OF THE WEEK'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function week {
  TIME="$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function week {
  TIME="$1"
}
```

--syntax editing slowed me down ;)